# How to calculate the quantification of qPCR to the equivalent of the number of nuclei in fungi?

Tags: dna, molecular-genetics, pcr, mycology

I have a question about the quantification through qPCR. The my question is: if I made the qPCR of a fungal functional gene, how is possible to obtain from the quantification number (in nanogram) the equivalent number in number of nuclei?

Comment: To clarify: you're asking about converting between copy number (which may be expressed in moles, molarity, or just a raw number) and nanograms of DNA?

Comment: If I obtain the quantification between nanogram to covert this number in number of nuclei. Because in one paper I found this sentece: "As few as 148 fg of Verticillium dahliae DNA were detected and quantified (through qPCR), which is equivalent to five nuclei". How is possible to make this convertion? @Punintended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment:

> "As few as 148 fg of Verticillium dahliae DNA were detected and quantified (through qPCR), which is equivalent to five nuclei". How is possible to make this convertion?

The [*Verticillium dahliae* JR2 genome](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/assembly/GCA_000400815.2) is 36.2 Mb.  Assuming this organism is haploid and dsDNA has an average mass of 660 g/mol per base pair, that means the molar mass of the genome is 2.40 × 10<sup>10</sup> g/mol.  Therefore, 5 nuclei will contain 8.30 × 10<sup>-24</sup> mol of your genome.  Multiplying the molar mass by the number of moles gives us a mass of 1.99 × 10<sup>-13</sup> g, or 199 fg, which is close to your cited value.